# I would like to use a character variable with scanf many times

Tags: c

In my program I must store input characters in variables and then add them to arrays. But is there a way to use the same variable each time?

```
char str1,str2;
printf("insert character");
scanf("%c",&str1);
printf("%c",str1);

printf("insert character");
scanf("%c",&str2);
printf("%c",str2);
```

I would like to do something like this but using one variable. Also can I use scanf more than 1 times? It seems the executable stops before the second character is given.

Comment: Do you mean you haven't tried `scanf("%c",&str1); printf("%c",str1);  scanf("%c",&str1); printf("%c",str1);`?! Or do you want something else. It stops probably because you didn't consume a new line after the 1st one. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129460/1133179.

Comment: Not getting what the problem is actually. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: Please provide some more context on the actual problem you are trying to solve. Are you familiar with `fgets(3)`/`getc(3)`?

Comment: Replace `printf("%c",strX);` with `printf("'%c'",strX);` and have a close look at the result.

Comment: Note: recommend to check the result of `scanf()`.  Is it `1` as expected?  Better yet, use `int ch = fgetc(stdin)` if code only needs to read 1 `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `scanf()` more than once. Your problem is not actually because of `scanf();`, Its with your input, To give input for first `scanf()` in your program, what we naturally do is we type(through keyboard) a character and hit ENTER KEY,Under the hood when you hit ENTER KEY a `'\n'` character is produced which is read by your second `scanf()` ,that's why your second `scanf()` is not waiting for input from you as you expected, You need to clear this `'\n'` manually when you use `%c`.(when `%d %f %s` are used `'\n'` are automatically removed that's why we don't face this problem when using them).

```
To solve problem you can use "%c" like this " %c" (note space before %c, this skips '\n' characters) 

scanf(" %c",&str1);
printf("%c",str1);
//code to add them to array's  
scanf(" %c",&str1);//Have Re-Used the same variable str1. 
printf("%c",str1);
```